# FindMinimumCost Flow and its parallelization

Tags: graphs-and-networks, parallelization

I would like to parallelize a specific implementation of FindMinimumCostFlow but doubt this can be easily done.

Nevertheless, I have tried but failed to find attempts to do so.

If you know of an attempt, please identify the URL or pub that describes any such effort.

Thanks.

Comment: You mean the builtin function `FindMinimumCostFlow`?  That can't be parallelized by users.  Wolfram would have to reimplement a parallel version (unless it's already parallel).  If you are concerned about speed and you are thinking about going far enough to write parallel code, then definitely don't use Mathematica.  Implement it in C++.

Comment: Thanks, Szabolcs.  I was afraid that'd be the answer but needed to be sure.